# Removing delay in UART communication layer

Tags: stm32, c, uart

I'm writing to a UART Device. So I'm doing the following:

I'm transmitting the message as follows:

```
    HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart5, data, size);
    uint8_t d;
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart5, &d, 1);
    push_single(&_readBuffer, d); // push to ring buffer
```

Then I'm reeving the data and pushing it to ringbuffer

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if (huart == &huart5)
    {
        if (!isFull(&_readBuffer))
        {
            uint8_t data;
            HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart5, &data, 1);
            if(data !='\000')
            {   
                push_single(&_readBuffer, data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in main i have to wait for data to be arrived and check if it's ok or not. I want to remove that delay:

```
char sendATcommand(const char *ATcommand, const char *expected_answer, unsigned int timeout)
{

  char x = 0, answer = 0;
  char response[200];
  unsigned long previous;

  memset(response, '\0', 200); // Initialize the string


  safe_flushReceiveBuffers();

  safe_write(ATcommand, strlen(ATcommand));
  HAL_Delay(timeout); // delay until message arrive
  previous = HAL_GetTick();
  ;

  // this loop waits for the answer
  do
  {
    uint8_t byte_avil = safe_bytesAvailable();
    if (byte_avil != 0)
    {
      // if there are data in the UART input buffer, reads it and checks for the asnwer
      response[x] = safe_read_single();
      x++;
      // check if the desired answer  is in the response of the module
      if (strstr(response, expected_answer) != NULL)
      {
        printf("\n");
        answer = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  // Waits for the asnwer with time out
  while ((answer == 0) && ((HAL_GetTick() - previous) < timeout));

  return answer;
}
```

**2nd problem**:

I'm also receiving some garbage characters from the UART + correct message. I don't know from where those characters come from.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the "HAL_Delay(timeout);" line? From the code it looks this line is not necessary, so what happens if you remove it?

Comment: @AndersPetersson If I remove it, I don't receive a complete message, not all the bytes are received.

Comment: @AndersPetersson The buffer is filled with garbage characters when I remove the delay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HAL_UART_Receive_IT() only initiates UART receive. It doesn't wait until any data is received. Thus, when you check the variable 'd' straight afterwards, the byte might have been received... but maybe not. Only in HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback() can you be sure the data has been set to a valid value.

To complicate matters, if you have fast UART speed your code might not yet have setup the UART driver to receiving the next byte when the byte arrives.

What you should do is a single call to HAL_UART_Receive_IT() to start saving the maximum number of bytes to a large enough buffer, then check from you non-interrupt code if new data has been written by checking huart->RxXferCount or huart->pRxBuffPtr.
When you have received the last byte, stop the UART or simply ignore further data.

Pseudocode:

```
uint8_t buffer[200];
HAL_UART_Receive_IT(huart, buffer, 200);
uint8_t* nextToProcess = &buffer[0];
while (!timeout) {
  if (huart->pRxBuffPtr > nextToProcess) {
    uint8_t received = *nextToProcess;
    nextToProcess++;
    // Handle the 'received' byte here, checking for end-of-transmission
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some pseudocode

Comment: Added psuedocode.